# .NET6 - Integration test with Entity Framework Core gives tracking error

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, integration-testing

I've created an `AppFactory` class which is used by all test classes through `IClassFixture` to setup a consistent startpoint for all the test classes. Every test class gets it's own docker database, through the use of the TestContainer package.

```
private readonly TestcontainerDatabase _dbContainer =
    new TestcontainersBuilder<PostgreSqlTestcontainer>()
        .WithDatabase(new PostgreSqlTestcontainerConfiguration
        {
            Database = "integration_test",
            Username = "integration_test",
            Password = "integration_test"
        })
        .Build();
```

```
builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
{
    services.RemoveAll(typeof(IHostedService));

    services.RemoveDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.RemoveAll<DbContext>();

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(_dbContainer.ConnectionString)
    );
```

This Appfactory inherits from `WebApplicationFactory<IAppMarker>, IAsyncLifetime`. In the `InitializeAsync` of the `AppFactory` I seed the database. However when more then 1 class is testing in parallel I get issues with the tracking of Entityframework. Even though every test class has it's own database.

```
System.InvalidOperationException The instance of entity type 'Country' cannot be tracked because
another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. 
When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given 
key value is attached.
```

I've tried adding `context.ChangeTracker.Clear();` to the seeder, which decreases the chance of the error occuring, but it can still occur. I expect entity framework to create a different tracker for each test class/database, so that this error does not occur.

I've also tried to create a new context for each test with AddDbContextFactory however this also has had no effect.

Comment: For each test create new `DbContext`

Comment: Disable parallel runs